# How to make responsive menu?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a responsive navigation menu using CSS for my website, but I cannot manage that.  I already tried some things as you can see in my styles. My header is already responsive, but I can't manage the navigation bar. The problem is when I click on the navigation bar, the nav menu is not shown.

```
<header>  

  <div class="navigation" id="navigation">
   <h4 class="logo">
     <span class="fashion">Fashion</span><span class="com">.com</span>
   </h4>
  <div class="offer">
    <p class="offer">Get Up To <strong>30%</strong> Off New Arrivals                                    
    <a class="shop" href="#">Shop Now</a></p>
  </div>

<!------------------ Navigation------------------->

  <nav class="navbar">
      <a href="#home" class="active" id="nav-link" aria-current="page">Home</a>
      <a href="#about" class="nav-link" id="nav-link">About</a>
      <a href="#collection" class="nav-link" id="nav-link">Collection</a>
      <a href="#contact" class="nav-link" id="nav-link">Contact</a>
      <a href="" class="nav-link" id="icon-link"><ion-icon name="person-sharp"></ion-icon></a>
      <a href="" class="nav-link" id="icon-link2"><ion-icon name="cart-sharp"></ion-icon></a>
      <a href="" class="nav-link btn red" id="nav-link">Log in/Sign up</a>
    </nav>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" id="toggler">
  <label for="toggler" class="fas fa-bars"></label>
  </div>
</header>
```

```
      .navigation .fa-bars{
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        color: #121212;
        padding: .5rem 1.5rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
      }
      .navbar{
        position: absolute;
        top:100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        border-top: .1rem solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
        background-color:whitesmoke;
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 0 0);
      }
      .navigation #toggler:checked ~ .navbar {
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
      }
      .navbar a {
        margin: .4rem;
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 1rem;
        background-color:white;
        display: block;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using general sibling selector in your toggler that will select sibling placed next to it , You have to just change the position of your toggler on the top of navbar or you can just use a different selector.

Below is the code:

```
<header>  

  <div class="navigation" id="navigation">
   <h4 class="logo">
     <span class="fashion">Fashion</span><span class="com">.com</span>
   </h4>
  <div class="offer">
    <p class="offer">Get Up To <strong>30%</strong> Off New Arrivals                                    
    <a class="shop" href="#">Shop Now</a></p>
  </div>

<!------------------ Navigation------------------->
  <input type="checkbox" name="" id="toggler">
  <label for="toggler" class="fas fa-bars"></label>
  <nav class="navbar">
      <a href="#home" class="active" id="nav-link" aria-current="page">Home</a>
      <a href="#about" class="nav-link" id="nav-link">About</a>
      <a href="#collection" class="nav-link" id="nav-link">Collection</a>
      <a href="#contact" class="nav-link" id="nav-link">Contact</a>
      <a href="" class="nav-link" id="icon-link"><ion-icon name="person-sharp"></ion-icon></a>
      <a href="" class="nav-link" id="icon-link2"><ion-icon name="cart-sharp"></ion-icon></a>
      <a href="" class="nav-link btn red" id="nav-link">Log in/Sign up</a>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>
```

```
  .navigation .fa-bars{
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        color: #121212;
        padding: .5rem 1.5rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
      }
      .navbar{
        position: absolute;
        top:100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        border-top: .1rem solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
        background-color:whitesmoke;
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 0 0);
      }
      .navigation #toggler:checked ~ .navbar {
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
      }
      .navbar a {
        margin: .4rem;
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 1rem;
        background-color:white;
        display: block;
      }
```